# How to remove error -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocation

I am updating my live app using MKMapKit and CLLocation. The app has not been updated since ios 6. I have updated and extracts of my viewdidload is as follows:

```
if (nil == locationManager)
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
[ locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] )   {

  UIAlertView *locationNotRunning= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Location Services are not enabled.  Application will terminate."
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles:nil];
[locationNotRunning show];
[self  performSelector:@selector(dismissNamedAlert:) withObject:locationNotRunning afterDelay:13];
  }
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) { locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO; }

then in the same method, the following:


CGRect availableArea = CGRectMake(0 , 0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 110); /
mapView = [[ MKMapView alloc ] initWithFrame:availableArea];


[mapView setDelegate:self];
  [mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
  [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
  [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
  mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
  [self.view addSubview:mapView ];
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation ];
```

Query is as follows:
1.     Is there anything missing as now the app has been complied in ios 9 and for ios 8 and 9?

2. I have changed the mapView snipet and put it before the location code

However I am getting the same following error:

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have the authorisation keys added to your plist ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` keys to your app plist.

Adding these two to `plist` is now mandatory from `ios8` onwards.

Also note that, you need to use `UIAlertController` instead of `UIAlertView` .`UIAlertView` is deprecated .

Comment: I have used only  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription.  Should both be used? Thanks for the advice on the UIAlertController.

Comment: Yes . Both are necessary

Comment: Thanks.  Very much appreciated.